# How to enable transaction with activemq camel component

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic, apache-karaf, blueprint-osgi, camel-jms

While consuming message from JMS queue I wish to decide whether consuming process is success or fail, In case of failure I wish that activemq redeliver the message again after some time like 1 minute. Later on based on delivery count I may send it to DLQ.

I found examples to achieve same with java code like session with different acknowledgement mode or making the session transacted but could not get how to achieve same with blueprint file.

```
     <reference id="testIdempotencyStore"
           interface="javax.sql.DataSource"
           filter="(osgi.jndi.service.name=TestContext)">
</reference>

<bean id="simulatorMessages" class="org.apache.camel.processor.idempotent.jdbc.JdbcMessageIdRepository">
    <argument ref="testIdempotencyStore" />
    <argument value="jmsTest" />
</bean>

<reference id="txMgr" interface="javax.transaction.TransactionManager" />

<bean id="xaConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQXAConnectionFactory">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="${activemq.url}" />
    <property name="watchTopicAdvisories" value="false" />
    <property name="userName" value="${activemq.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${activemq.password}" />
    <property name="redeliveryPolicy" >
        <bean class="org.apache.activemq.RedeliveryPolicy" >
            <property name="maximumRedeliveries" value="0" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jcaConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.JcaPooledConnectionFactory"
      init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="txMgr"/>
    <property name="maxConnections" value="10" />
    <property name="name" value="amq" />
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="xaConnectionFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jmsTxConf" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQConfiguration">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jcaConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="requestTimeout" value="10000" />
    <property name="transactionTimeout" value="30" />
    <property name="cacheLevelName" value="CACHE_NONE" />
</bean>

<bean id="activemq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent" >
    <property name="configuration" ref="jmsTxConf" />
</bean>

<camelContext id="TestContext-jms-dispatcher" trace="false" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint" >
    <route id="externalNotificationsDispatchRoute" >
        <from uri="activemq:queue:{{vqueue.name}}" />
        <idempotentConsumer messageIdRepositoryRef="simulatorMessages">
            <header>customId</header>
            <to uri="vm:notificationConsumer" />
        </idempotentConsumer>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

Comment: I created a full XA example with JMS, camel and a database some time ago. See https://github.com/Talend/tesb-rt-se/tree/master/examples/tesb/ebook . It is a Talend esb example but works on plain karaf too.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't done so already, read through [this chapter](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_fuse/6.2.1/html/transaction_guide/xajms) to learn more about how JMS XA Transactions work in JBoss Fuse.

You're missing the Spring `PlatformTransactionManager`and a few other things.
Here's an example of a configuration that should work:

```
<!-- Service reference to Spring’s PlatformTransactionManager -->
<reference id=”osgiPlatformTransactionManager”
    interface=”org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager”>

<!-- Service reference to JTA TransactionManager -->
<reference id=”osgiJtaTransactionManager”
    interface=”javax.transaction.TransactionManager”>

<!-- JMS TX endpoint -->
<bean id=”activemq” class=”org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent”>
    <property name=”configuration” ref=”jmsTxConfig”>
</bean>

<bean id=”jmsTxConfig” class=”org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration”>
    <property name=”connectionFactory” ref=”jmsXaPoolConnectionFactory” />
    <property name=”transactionManager” ref=”osgiPlatformTransactionManager” />
    <!-- transacted must be set to “false” for XA transactions -->
    <!-- as it is only meant to be used with local transactions -->
    <property name=”transacted” value=”false” />
</bean>

<!-- The connection factory wrapper to enable auto-enlisting -->
<bean id=”jmsXaPoolConnectionFactory”
    class=”org.apache.activemq.pool.JcaPooledConnectionFactory”>
    <property name=”name” value=”MyXaResource” />
    <property name=”maxConnections” value=”1” />
    <property name=”connectionFactory” ref=”jmsXaConnectionFactory” />
    <property name=”transactionManager” ref=”osgiJtaTransactionManager” />
</bean>

<bean id=”jmsXaConnectionFactory”
    class=”org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQXAConnectionFactory”>
    <property name=”brokerURL” value=”${activemq.url}” />
    <property name=”userName” value=”${activemq.user}” />
    <property name=”password” value=”${activemq.password}” />
    <property name="watchTopicAdvisories" value="false" />
    <property name="redeliveryPolicy" >
    <bean class="org.apache.activemq.RedeliveryPolicy" >
        <property name="maximumRedeliveries" value="0" />
    </bean>
</property>
</bean>

<!-- ActiveMQ XA Resource Manager -->
<bean id=”resourceManager” class=”org.apache.activemq.pool.ActiveMQResourceManager”
    init-method=”recoverResource”>
    <property name=”transactionManager” ref=”osgiJtaTransactionManager” />
    <property name=”connectionFactory” ref=”jmsXaConnectionFactory” />
    <property name=”resourceName” value=”activemq.default” />
</bean>

<!-- Transaction Policy to be referenced by the transacted-component in a route -->
<bean id=”txPolicy” class=”org.apache.camel.spring.spi.SpringTransactionPolicy”>
    <property name=”transactionManager” ref=”osgiPlatformTransactionManager” />
    <!-- PROPAGATION_REQUIRED is the default value if a behavior is not set -->
    <property name=”propagationBehaviorName” value=”PROPAGATION_REQUIRED” />
</bean>
```